# Android - How to set my application as an "image provider"

Tags: android, android-intent

In android, when you want to select a picture in an application, the OS lets you choose between taking a photo or using the "gallery" app.
I would like my application to appear in that list, so that it can send an image file to the calling app.
I know that intents are made for this kinds of inter-app communications, but I don't know how I can tell Android that my app can provide image files for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think that intent-filters are the correct way to answer that problem.

This works by specifying which types of intents your app can handle. When another app starts an intent, Android will display your app as an option if the type of started intent passes your app's filtering.

[Intent filters on official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#exercise_intentfilter)

This works for showing the app in the menu for handling an image file selection.

The point is that I still can't find how to respond to the intent with an image.